# Is a D-Wave quantum computer able to do TD-DFT calculations?

Tags: quantum-chemistry, td-dft, excited-states, energy, quantum-computing

I was reading this paper ([Computing molecular excited states on a D‑Wave quantum annealer](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41598-021-98331-y)) and wondering if I can make a QUBO model for the equations used in the TD-DFT energy calculation for the singlet and triplet energies?

Answer (score 3):

### Any computation that can be solved on an ordinary classical computer can in theory be turned into a QUBO problem.

This includes TD-DFT calculations. We know this because the the [2-local Hamiltonian problem](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0406180) is [QMA complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QMA#Problems_in_QMA) and there exist gadgets (see pages 72-73 of [my book about gadgets for Hamiltonians](https://arxiv.org/abs/1901.04405v2)) that can transform arbitrary 2-local Hamiltonians into Ising Hamiltonians or QUBO problems if you include enough auxiliary spins/qubits (in the case of an Ising model) or binary variables (in the case of QUBO). The key phrase though, is "***if you include enough auxiliary spins/qubits/binary-variables***", and currently there are no examples of real-world problems for which solving QUBO is known to be an efficient way to do computations. Said another way: if there's a way to do TD-DFT calculations via solving QUBO problems, that is worthwhile to you as a researcher, it is not yet known, or else it ought to mentioned in an answer to one of the following questions:

- [Are there any real-world problems where quadratization helps to solve something that couldn't have been solved without quadratization?](https://or.stackexchange.com/q/1380/727)
- [What are some real-world applications of QUBO?](https://or.stackexchange.com/q/828/727)

My answers to the following questions may also be of interest to you:

- [Can QUBO solve this inverse Ising problem?](https://or.stackexchange.com/a/6620/727) [Operations Research Stack Exchange]
- [Can any binary problem be solved by a QUBO?](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/23309/2293) [Quantum Computing Stack Exchange]
- [Can operations research be used for protein folding?](https://or.stackexchange.com/a/5047/727) [Operations Research Stack Exchange]